# How to take square of variable as I(x^2) to add in linear model with loop?

Tags: r, linear-regression, formula

I generated something that takes data, which adds all column names to the linear regression, adds their interactions and their second degree of that variable, and uses step function to finds out the best linear regression model. I added both all column names and interactions but here I have a problem adding a second degree of the variables. I use the above-given code but it gives an

```
Error in (colnames(dpt)[i])^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator" error
```

Could anyone help? I really appreciate it.

```
for (i in colnames(dpt)) {
  lmod <- lmod %>% update(paste('. ~ . + I((colnames(dpt)[i])^2)'),
                          data = dpt)
}
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use stepwise selection methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/163114), though.

Comment: In addition to the advice about hte evils of stepwise procedures, one should also be aware that using `+poly( ..., 2)` would result in more statistically "refined" results. With `I(var^2)` you may well create collinearity and conclude that the quadratic term is significant when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sprintf`.

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)

v <- names(mtcars)[-(1:2)]

res <- lapply(v, \(x) update(fit, sprintf('. ~ . + I(%s^2)', x)))
```

Or, if you are into pipes:

```
res <- lapply(v, \(x) fit |> update(sprintf('. ~ . + I(%s^2)', x)))
```

Or if you cannot do without the `for` loop:

```
res <- vector(mode='list', length=length(v))
for (i in seq_along(v)) {
  res[[i]] <- fit |> update(sprintf('. ~ . + I(%s^2)', v[i]))
}
```

### Gives

```
res
# [[1]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(disp^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl    I(disp^2)  
# 3.543e+01   -2.246e+00   -2.115e-05  
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(hp^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl      I(hp^2)  
# 3.705e+01   -2.641e+00   -2.374e-05  
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(drat^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl    I(drat^2)  
# 31.6655      -2.4568       0.2745  
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(wt^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl      I(wt^2)  
# 35.8818      -1.9282      -0.3423  
# 
# 
# [[5]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(qsec^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl    I(qsec^2)  
# 43.73138     -3.15264     -0.01285  
# 
# 
# [[6]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(vs^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl      I(vs^2)  
# 39.6250      -3.0907      -0.9391  
# 
# 
# [[7]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(am^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl      I(am^2)  
# 34.522       -2.501        2.567  
# 
# 
# [[8]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(gear^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl    I(gear^2)  
# 36.03695     -2.76010      0.08013  
# 
# 
# [[9]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + I(carb^2), data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl    I(carb^2)  
# 37.55404     -2.74723     -0.04454
```